# What is the difference between a Boeing Line number and a Block number?

Tags: terminology, boeing

We know that every Boeing aircraft has a Line number, Block number, and MSN number. I want to know what what does it mean by this Line Number or Block number. and what are the difference among these terms.

Comment: The answer seems to be [here](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=346131#post_content4099807).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is Boeing's Examples

Block numbers

- ZA001 Onwards - B787-8
- ZB001 Onwards - B787-9
- ZC001 Onwards - B787-10
- ZD001 Onwards - rebuild of prototypes
- ZE001 Onwards - B787-9 with customizations

Line numbers are the serial number of the aircraft of that aircraft type

Serial Number is the manufacturers serial (basically the number of aircraft they have built up to that aircraft)

Airbus doesn't use the Boeing Line/Serial numbers, they use a different system where the aircraft serial number is in fact the aircraft line number and the total # of the aircraft being built.

Answer (score 4):

Boeing has the following known numbering styles.

- **MSN** (Manufacture serial number) unique to all Boeing aircraft, no repeats
- **l/n** (Line Number) unique in most case to Boeing model. *Reset to 1, with 737NG*
- **Customer Code** (dropped since on 777,767,737,747) [never applied to 787 and 737 MAX, and will not be applied to the 777X either.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Boeing_customer_codes).
- **Variable Number** (treated like L/n but with single alpha prefix)
  P = 737, Y = 737NG, R = 747, N = 757, V = 767, W = 777, Z = 787.
- **Variable Code**
  As listed by David Cummings is the example best known on the 787 series as used in some usage with testing prototypes with their FAA Reg Number/Tail numbers.
  Treated like blocks in production for certain airlines hence the block reference or label also known as tabulation number.
  Some number are skipped in the above sequence listed, when can, but no hard and fast rules apply to this process.

I am actively searching for the complete list of Variable Code / Numbers for most 7X7 series aircraft. (have most 747, all 787)

Comment: Hi Jets - you should contact me I have most f not all boeings stuff available